# Parametrization of skew lines for saddle like surface

Tags: linear-algebra, surfaces

Given 2 skew lines $m_1$ and $m_2$ which do not lie in $\pi$. The surface is the set of all lines that intersect both $m_1$ and $m_2$ that are parallel to $\pi$.

To make things easier we can consider $\pi$ as the xz-axis. Since the combination of all lines can generate lines that are not parallel to $\pi$, we can restrict to only have the defining points at the same height.

Comment: Are you saying that all lines should be parallel to the x-z plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line must join points on $m_1$ and $m_2$ having the same $y$ co-ordinate.

Let the equation of $m_k$ be $l_k = \vec r_k + \vec v_k t$

with $\vec r_k = (r_{kx}, r_{ky}, r_{kz} )$

and $v_k = (v_{kx}, v_{ky}, v_{kz} )$

Let $\vec p_1(a)$ be the point on $m_1$ with $\vec p_1.(0,1,0) = a$

$$\vec p_1(a) = \vec r_1 + \vec v_1 \bigg ( \frac{ a-r_{1y}}{ v_{1y}} \bigg  ) $$

Let $\vec p_2(a)$ be the point on $m_2$ with $\vec p_2.(0,1,0) = a$

$$\vec p_2(a) = \vec r_2 + \vec v_2 \bigg ( \frac{ a-r_{2y}}{ v_{2y}} \bigg  ) $$

So the surface $\pi$ can be parameterized as...
$$ \pi(a,t) = \vec p_1(a) + t \bigg(\vec p_2(a)  - \vec p_1(a) \bigg) $$

Answer (score 0):

The two skew lines $\,m_i\,$ are parametrized by

$$ p_i + t\,\vec v_i \quad \text{ for }
 \quad i=1,2. $$

The planes parallel to the plane $\,\pi\,$ are
parametrized by

$$ p + t\,\vec v \quad \text{ where }
 \quad \vec v \perp \vec v_\pi. $$

Suppose that the $\,v_i\,$ are such that
$\,\vec v_i\cdot \vec v_\pi = 1 \,$
(which can be ensured by scaling the $\,\vec v_i\,$).
Also suppose that the $\,p_i\,$ are in a plane parallel to
$\,\pi\,$ (which can be ensured by using the two points of
intersection of the skew lines with such a plane).
Define the lines $\,\pi_t\,$ by

$$ \pi_t(\lambda) := \lambda(p_1 +t\,\vec v_1) +
(1-\lambda)(p_2 + t\,\vec v_2). $$

For each $\,t,\,$ the line $\,\pi_t\,$ intersects
$\,m_1\,$ and $\,m_2.\,$ Each line $\,\pi_t\,$ is
in a plane parallel to $\,\pi.$
Thus, the $\,\pi_t\,$ form a ruled surface.

Comment: This is more or less what i did, however i am trying to insert what you suppose directly inside the parametrization to make coding the surface easier. That is what i'm struggling with.

Comment: @mamamjama Please state exactly what your are starting with (that is, coordinates of the given data) in the body of the question and then I can write a better answer.

Comment: I updated the question a bit to try and make it clearer. What you did i'm pretty sure is correct. However, i'm trying to insert the supposition directly into the parametrization such to have the parallel to the plane restriction combined with the creation of the lines. So given the parametrization, one would only have to iterate over t and lambda to get the appropriate values without taking into account anything else. I'm not sure if this is any clearer now

Comment: @mamamjama I added a little more detail. It would help tremendously if you gave a numerical example of what the given data are.